# jQuery accordion grouping

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a list of a model to a view with an accordion:

```
 <div id="accordion" style="display:none">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <h2 id= 'header-@Model[i].ID' class="header" style="background-color:whitesmoke"><span class="newspan">@Model[i].user.FullName</span>&nbsp
                <span style="color:orange">@Model[i].ReasonDescription</span>
                <span id="spansite-@Model[i].ID" style="font-style:italic;color:black">@Model[i].ProgramSite&nbsp-&nbsp @Model[i].Location</span>
                <span id="span-@Model[i].ID" style="font-style:italic;color:red" align="center"></span>
                <img id="img-@Model[i].ID" src="~/Images/yes.gif" alt="" style="display:none" class="yescheck" align="right" height="12" width="12"/>
            </h2>
            <div id="div+@Model[i].user.ID">
                @Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model[i].user.ID, new { @id = "txtId" + @Model[i].ID})
                @Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model[i].user.userSSN, new { @id = "txtSSN" + @Model[i].ID})
                @Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model[i].user.DODID, new { @id = "txtDodid" + @Model[i].ID})
                <table id="user+@Model[i].ID" style="font-size:small; width:100%" class="table_body">
      //////etc
```

They are all in a sorted order.  Is there a way to create groups of this list so that the there are several accordions?  Do I have to create groups in the model first?  Any ideas?

Comment: The groups are by the reason description.

Comment: the reason is text

Comment: That could be a little challenging. You'd need to somehow parse that property in the loop or group them beforehand on the back end. Please update your question to add this new information.

Comment: This isn't a jQuery problem, it's a c# problem. Linq's `GroupBy` might be a good place to start.